# Flying to the USA on a tourist visa to get the COVID vaccination

Tags: covid-19, medical, california

My 52-year-old wife (non-US citizen with valid visa) is talking about flying to Los Angeles along with our 18-year-old (US citizen) so that BOTH can get the one-shot vaccination at Walmart's or similar. The delays in the delivery in our country are very bad, and their age-groups are slated until the end of the year for receiving the shot.

I can make an appointment for them at the appropriate agency, but I am worried that my wife will get turned away for being non-citizen...

BTW, we have insurance cards that cover international travel...

According to the [Walmart's site](https://corporate.walmart.com/covid-vaccine)...

> What do I need to bring to my appointment?
>
> 1. On the day of your appointment, please bring your insurance card if you have one.
> 2. CDC does not require proof of age, occupation, or any other type of credentials; instead it relies on you to attest that you meet current eligibility.

Is it true that eligibility is based solely on "word"?

Comment: I'm next door in Nevada.  There was a simple form my wife filled out with eligibility requirements (this was back in February).  They did not appear to do any checking of it, although I think they had enough to verify one of them.  The other they most certainly did not have the info to verify.  I got a waste shot a few weeks before I was eligible, the only thing they cared about was 16+.  (And the only requirement for getting the second shot was having gotten the first.)  Neither of us presented anything that would show citizenship.

Comment: There must be several hundred thousand noncitizens living in California.  It would be a serious detriment to public health to restrict vaccinations to citizens.

Comment: Citizenship and immigration status are definitely not considered for vaccinations. But residency might matter. At least earlier in the vaccination campaign, some states and counties restricted COVID-19 vaccines to residents of those states or counties. I can't find anything from California or LA county now that explicitly restricts it to residents.